# Работа с файлами си

Tags: c, fopen

Скопировать из файла File1 в файл Fail2 все строки, которые не содержат цифры . Нужно реализовать на си . Этот код работает не корректно он не записывает строку только если число в начале , а если оно в середине или конце тогда строка будет записана , в принципе я понимаю почему так но как реализовать чтобы оно правильно копировало строки не знаю .

```
FILE* read = fopen("C:/Files/File1.txt", "r");
if (read != NULL)
{
    char chfile[100000];
    int i, j, Words = 0;
    char c[2];
    char symbol = ' ';
    char *estr = "";
    char String[1000];

    FILE* write = fopen("C:/Files/File2.txt", "w");
    fclose(write);
    strcpy(String, "\0");
        while (1)
        {
            estr = fgets(chfile, sizeof(chfile), read);
            if (chfile[0] != '1' && chfile[0]!= '2' && chfile[0]!= '3' && chfile[0]!= '4' && chfile[0]!= '5'
                    && chfile[0]!= '6' && chfile[0]!= '7' && chfile[0]!= '8' && chfile[0]!= '9' && chfile[0]!= '0')
            {

                for (i = 0; i < strlen(chfile); i++)
                {
                    symbol = estr[i];
                    sprintf(c, "%c", symbol);
                    strcat(String, c);

                    FILE* add = fopen("C:/Files/File2.txt", "a");
                    fputs(String, add);

                    fclose(add);
                    strcpy(String, "\0");
                }
            }
        }

}else
{
    printf("\n");
    fclose(read);
 }
getch();
```

Comment: [man fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file_in file_out\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fin, *fout;

    if ((fin = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
    {
        perror(argv[1]);
        return 2;
    }

    if ((fout = fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL)
    {
        fclose(fin);
        perror(argv[2]);
        return 3;
    }

    size_t const bufflen = 1024;
    char buffer[bufflen];

    while (fgets(buffer, bufflen, fin))
        if (!strpbrk(buffer, "0123456789"))
            fputs(buffer, fout);

    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```